# Need to extract an interface, but one method is extra in implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I write message transport that allows to transfer messages from one object to another. So it has methods like `send` and `receive`

And I have two kind of implementations:

- InMemoryTransport transfers message between threads and based on blocking qeueue
- SocketTransport transferts messages throught socket

`InMemoryTransport` implementation:

```
public class InMemoryTransport {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, BlockingQueue<Parcel>> parcelList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void send(Parcel parcel) {
        parcelList.computeIfAbsent(parcel.getReceiverName(), (n) -> new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()).add(parcel);
    }

    public Parcel receive(String recipient) {
        Parcel poll;
        try {
            poll = parcelList.computeIfAbsent(recipient, (n) -> new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()).take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return poll;
    }
}
```

`SocketTransport` implementation:

```
public class SocketParcelTransport {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, SocketWraper> listeners = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void register(String compomentName, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        listeners.putIfAbsent(compomentName, new SocketWraper(socket));
    }

    public void send(Parcel message) {
        try {
            listeners.get(message.getReceiverName()).getOutputStream().writeObject(message);
            listeners.get(message.getReceiverName()).getOutputStream().flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Parcel receive(String recipient) {
        try {
            return (Parcel) listeners.get(recipient).getInputStream().readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore. Just return null in case of io exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    class SocketWraper {
        // main idea of this class is to create input and output stream from socket
        public ObjectInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            ...
        }

        public ObjectOutputStream getOutputStream() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to extract an interface for these two implementations. Both implementations have two same methods that can be easily extracted: `void send(Parcel parcel)` and `Parcel receive(String recipient)`
But `SocketParcelTransport` have method `void register(String name, Socket socket)`. I don't know what to do with it.

I can make method `register(String compomentName)` in `InMemoryTransport` but what should I pass as the second parameter? Passing `BlockingQueue<Parcel>` will be really bad idea because I want to encapsulate such details.

If I will not extract `void register(String compomentName, Socket socket)` to interface, how can I use `SocketParcelTransport`? Becase when you use DI - you only work with interfaces

### Update 1:

Create default method in interface, so the interface will look like

```
public interface ParcelTransport {

    default <T> void register(String componentName, T dataSource) {
     // do nothing   
    };

    void send(Parcel message);

    Parcel receive(String recipient);
}
```

in that case my SocketParcelTransport will look in the following way, and how can I pass `Socket` to `register()`

```
public class SocketParcelTransport implements ParcelTransport {

    @Override
    public <T> void register(String componentName, T dataSource) {
        Socket socket = dataSource;    // how Can I pass socket here??
    }
```

If I change my interface to

```
public interface ParcelTransport<T> {

    default void register(String componentName, T dataSource) {
     // do nothing   
    };
   ...
```

in that case my `InMemoryTransport` class will give me warining `raw use of parametrized class`

```
public class ThreadsParcelTransport implements ParcelTransport {
...
}
```

Comment: You can have a default method in your interface?

Comment: @trim24 please see my update

Answer (score 0):

- Just create two interfaces (one extends another one). The first one
  will have common methods inside and the second one extra method.
- Default interface method (move listeners list to the interface)

Comment: "move listeners list to the interface" - What do you mean by saying that?

Comment: "Just create two interfaces" - what interface should I use in DI?

Comment: it's better to use both and inject the required one. So, two beans with two interfaces. (but polymorphism is still working ) Otherwise, you can cast it to get access to the 3rd method.

Comment: "move listeners list to the interface" won't work it will be a static field, sorry

Comment: for now I see cast is the best option